Tricky Bar Graph or Histogram

I am trying to determine if this is a bar graph or a histogram. It's the distribution of American families by income. This has been such a struggle for me, but I'm sure there's a simple explanation.
By definition, a bar graph has gaps between the columns, which this graph does.
However, this graph uses quantitative data, which makes me want to say it's a histogram.
On the other end, there isn't an even interval. Some of the columns have a range of 5, 10 25.
I know histograms can have different bin widths, but the widths of each bar are the same.
This also follows endpoint convention, which is necessary for a histogram.
This has been driving me crazy for the past day. Samples of bar graphs online are charts of how many people like the color blue, or red, or green.
This is obviously different and is meant to trip you up I suppose, but I would love any help I can receive.

It's just simply wrong. It's like a map which is not to scale. Shouldn't class width be constant for bar graphs/ histograms?

@Gwen I'm not quite sure I understand. I believe a bar graph always has a constant width, but a histograms class width (column width?) can differ

I think most statistics textbooks would call this a bar graph, not a histogram, because equal distances on the horizontal axis don’t correspond to equal differences of the variable on that axis. (The fact that there are small gaps is not the key issue in distinguishing the two graph types, but the non-equal intervals are.) At least in my experience, I do not think histograms “can have different bin widths” (within the same graph).

I think it's the quite opposite. Histograms can infact have different bin widths. Bar graphs don't.

If a histogram has different bin widths, the bar widths would be proportional to the bin widths. Generally, histograms have equal bar widths that correspond to equal bin widths, but histograms can have unequal bar widths (and correspondingly unequal bin widths), such as this one from Wikipedia: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Travel_time_histogram_total_n_Stata.png . However, a graph of frequency/count with a horizontal axis variable that is a scale variable would not be called a histogram if it had unequal bin widths represented by equal-width bars.
